# What is best ORM with these requirements

Tags: c#, .net, orm

I'm looking for a good ORM for an upcoming project.

The database will have around 1000 to 1200 tables, and it will be in Both SQL Server and Oracle, which will be used depending of customers enterprise needs.
Also a few part of the project will work with WCF services.
I want a designer or something like that.
Good support of LINQ.
Acceptable performance.

I have tried DataObjects.Net but it doesn't have any designer. We can't code all that tables nor use code generator. And I'm not sure if DataObjects.Net supports switching database.
Also I'm familiar with EF4 but it can't support both databases together, and switching databases manually(modifying the edmx file) is such a pain in ... for maintenance job.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Seems [OpenAccess](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) and [LLBLGEN Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/) have designer but I don't have experience with them.

Comment: I know of NO one with designer that works well with that number of objects. The best you can get is pretty much LLBLGEN Pro - simply because it is the ONLY one with a DECENT designer that even is usable with 1000-1200 entities (EntityFramework pretty much goes into "no designer" with this amount - it is totally unusable).

Comment: I think this question is specific enough to be exempt from the "not constructive" close reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would still vote for Entity Framework v4 - EF4.

After all:

- you can have multiple EDMX files, no problem - one for SQL Server, one for Oracle
- you could put those into their own class library, and then load or, or the other, or both, if needed, at runtime (e.g. by using the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com) or something of your own)
- you can easily target those EDMX files at databases using connection strings - really not hard at all

Comment: I second @marc. EF4 has designer support and good linq support and @marc's idea of keeping 2 EDMX files could ease the pain of multiple RDBMS support.

Comment: Actually if you have about 1200 tables, you should really not have just 1 edmx file. That would never work performance wise, considering all the tracking that the context would need to do.
You will still need to have multiple edmx for both oracle and sql server.

Comment: @Stephane: yes, good point - each EDMX shouldn't have a lot more than about 200 or so tables. Usually it's not all that difficult to partition your app into groups of 200 (or less) tables

Comment: That's good point, thanks. I'm going to use my own generator to generate POCO classes to pick one of EDMX files for each database which is going to be used.
And yes, we will definitively use separated EDMX files for different subsystems.

Comment: @Salar: In case you are interested, there is a [POCO T4 template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) in the visual studio code gallery that you can use (or modify to suit your needs).

Answer (score 2):

Given this information I would suggest to look into [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) (and/or [fluent-nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)).

The item you will have to look into is performance. This depends heavily on the nature of your application. 1,000 to 1,200 tables sounds massive, so I'd recommend to definitely run a number of meaningful performance tests (in addition to all the other tests) before you finalize the decision.

**Edit**: In fact the better starting place for NHibernate is [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info) (Thanks, Justin!).

Comment: Why NHibernate? In order to decrease database modeling to objects time, we want to use a designer or etc. Does NHibernate have any designer?

Comment: According to these tests http://ormbattle.net/ NHibernate doesn't act good comparing to others.

Comment: @Salor - It depends on the category, NHibernate does better in some than others and vice versa.

Comment: @Salor: I think ormbattle.net is a useful site as long as you take it with a pinch of salt. Have a look who created that site and what they do as their fulltime job. - To your first comment: Designer support - in my view - is only one of the factors to consider, some listed by ormbattle.net some not. There are many more and it depends on your situation which you consider and how you weigh them.

Comment: LLBLGen v3 can be used as designer for NHibernate and EF

Answer (score 2):

OpenAccess can also do the job for you. You could use the multiple .rlinq files and assembly-per-database approach as suggested with Entity Framework. The benefit I see for you would be the support you will get from Telerik as there is quite a chance for you to hit a rock or two while developing a solution of such proportions.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest NHibernate but the place to research it is definitely NHForge:

http://nhibernate.info/

Here is the high-level feature overview (including LINQ):

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-features.html

There are a few designers available, including LLBLGen Pro:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/commercial-product-ecosystem.html

NHibernate 3 is in alpha now but I know that it is already being used in production a few places.  That might be the best way to go for a new project.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The better place to start is NHForge. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to pick your ORM and designer tool separately.  For example, go with EF and LLBLGEN, or NHibernate and CodeSmith, or NHibernate and LLBLGEN, etc.

Comment: Good point, I'm going to use my own generator with EF4.